# Find and convert to NULL all duplicated values from the same column in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list `BELGIAN_COAST_list` containing hundreds of data frames (`df1`, `df2`, ...) of 15 columns X 1000 rows. The last column of each of these data frames is called `Chemicals` and contains some characters such as *Sulfate* or *Ammonia*. But many rows of this column `Chemicals` are duplicated within each dataframe (due to a technical issue with the measuring device).

I wish to convert the duplicated characters to `NULL` so that they just appear once in the entire column for each df of my list.

I tried to `unlist` my `BELGIAN_COAST_list` and then

```
BELGIAN_COAST$Chemicals[duplicated(BELGIAN_COAST$chemicals)] <- ""
```

In this case, the characters will only appear once in the merged entire data frame. I want that they appear once in each dataframe (`df1$Chemicals`, `df2$Chemicals`, ...) of my `BELGIAN_COAST_list`. Therefore I need to keep my data in a list of df.

Has someone any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base `R`:

```
lapply(BELGIAN_COAST_list, function(x) {
  dups <- duplicated(x[, ncol(x)]) 
  x[dups, ncol(x)] <- NA_character_ 
  x})
```

This is done positionally, by the last column. If you want to call the column by name then you can change `ncol(x)` to `"Chemicals"`.

---

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

purrr::map(BELGIAN_COAST_list, ~ dplyr::mutate(., across(last_col(), ~ ifelse(duplicated(.), NA_character_, .))))
```

Again to call by column name change `last_col()` to `Chemicals`: note the lack of quotation marks here.

In either event, if `Chemicals` is numeric then use `NA` instead of `NA_character_`.

Comment: So simple, so efficient! Thank you. I did not understand how R knows it is about the last column `Chemicals` but you explained it too.

Comment: You're welcome! `last_col` is in the library `tidyselect` and is a special function to select the last column. `ncol` returns the index of the last column and the code uses that to select the last column by its index.